# Can't format moment object to date and time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using a react component for Date picking which returns a moment object. Also, I'm using my custom component to select time and saving the value like this for example `3:30 pm` .

What I want to do is make this one moment object that I can later user and format however I want.

This is my current implementation but it's not working:

formatting the time is always returning AM

```
const time = moment(pickupTime.formattedTime, ['hh:mm a'])
        .locale('en')
        .format('hh:mm A');

const dateTime =
        startDay.locale('en').format('MMM Do YY') + // This is the Date which is a moment object
        ' ' +
        time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because string + string = string, you cannot get an object by concatenating strings.

What you need is to convert a string to a moment object:

```js
moment('24/12/2019 09:15:00', "DD MM YYYY hh:mm:ss");
```

Result:

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: '24/12/2019 09:15:00', _f: 'DD MM YYYY hh:mm:ss', _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
```

Check out https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/